# Windows YouTube client, borderless, always on top

Tags: windows, youtube

I'm looking for a Windows YouTube video player.

### It must have these features:

- Resizable window
- While playing only the video is shown, now unrelated stuff like similar videos or controls (like, share, etc.)

### Nice-to-have features

- Borderless window
- Always-on-top (player remains visible while focusing other windows)
- Free
- Open source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.en_GB.html) from VideoLAN can open YouTube videos with Control-N *for Open Network Stream* and the minimal interface is just that, (Ctrl-H or View-Minimal Interface).

- It is resizable, (or full screen), and  shows absolutely nothing but the video and a title bar in minimal mode.
- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Small *28MB on Windows at the moment*
- Windows, OS-X & Linux
- Also Andoriod, Windows Phone, iOS, Just about everything

### Playing From You-Tube with mininmal interface

[image]

Comment: oh nice thats awesome! It also has the "always on top" option

Comment: Yep, [How to disable all window borders from the VLC playback window](http://superuser.com/questions/201667/how-to-disable-all-window-borders-from-the-vlc-playback-window)

Comment: borderless too! ok. though it sucks imo (creates two windows and the borderless one is neither resizable nor movable, only via settings)